# VBA Code for disable the Right Click option in Excel for the current Workbook only

Tags: excel, vba

I have created multiple worksheets in my workbook.
I want to my users are not allowing to see the other sheets in excel.
Since I want to disable the right click option in Excel open event.

I have a piece of code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick (ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox ("Sorry Right Click is Disabled for this Workbook")
End Sub
```

The above code runs only after opening the Workbook and run the Macro.
I want to disable right click option the Workbook when opening the Workbook.

Comment: Can you explain more about what behaviour you're trying to prevent? There may be a better way of doing this (although the above code if placed in the `Workbook` module should work without any manual intervention (I just tested this in a currently open workbook -- I did not have to re-open the file nor run any macro, before it works).

Comment: If you don't want your users to see the other sheets, why don't you hide those sheets instead of trying to disable functionality of the program?

Comment: Why not set the sheets to `xlVeryHidden` and password-protect the VBA project?

Answer (score 4):

Try this, different parameters...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try the codes below: - Good Luck

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.CommandBars("Ply").Enabled = True
End Sub
```

And

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.CommandBars("Ply").Enabled = False
End Sub
```