# Disable specific sheet ("ply") right click option using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to disable (or hide) specific right click options on the Excel sheet/tab menu. I don't want to disable the entire menu [per this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206328/vba-code-for-disable-the-right-click-option-in-excel-for-the-current-workbook-on).

I've tried in both Excel 2010 & 2016, same result. The code runs fine but the options in the sheet right click menu are still enabled. I've tried using the control's name and ID to no avail.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls("cut").Enabled = False 'Works
    With Application.CommandBars("Ply")
        .Controls("Insert...").Enabled = False
        .Controls("&Select All Sheets").Enabled = False
        .Controls("Select All Sheets").Enabled = False
        .FindControl(ID:=946).Enabled = False '&Select All Sheets ID:946
       '.Enabled = False 'Works but don't want entire menu disabled
    End With
End Sub
```

After code, options are still enabled:

[image: Excel Sheet Right Click Menu Options]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is application level setting. What if the user is trying to do work that isn't in your "workbook application"?  It strikes me as an X - Y problem.  What are you trying to accomplish by trashing Excel the context menu?

Comment: This is a basic example of the issue I'm facing. My overall application adds menu options to this same "ply" menu when they are using my workbook and removes them with the user changes to a different workbook. That all works as designed. I'm trying to accomplish disabling or hiding the "Select All Sheets" option, is it not possible?

Comment: From [the top comment on the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206328/vba-code-for-disable-the-right-click-option-in-excel-for-the-current-workbook-on#comment35498520_23206328).  "Can you explain more about what behaviour you're trying to prevent? There may be a better way of doing this..."

Comment: I want to disable or hide the "Select All Sheets" option that is present when you right click on an Excel sheet tab. Alternatively, if there was a way to trap that call before the "Select all sheets" executed that would work too. I do NOT want to disable all right click functionality which is what that comment you linked to is doing.

Comment: No, the comment is asking why you need to disable parts of the UI in general. I completely understand what you're trying to accomplish - the question is ***why***. There may be a less intrusive way to do that than trashing the context menu.

Comment: When a user clicked "Select All Sheets" it was throwing an error in code that ran in the "Workbook_SheetActivate" event that was trying to run on all the sheets in the workbook (which were now selected). I was able to code around the issue but was curious as to how to disable/hide the "Select All Sheets" option entirely so my clients aren't tempted to click it. When I tried to disable it (like I do with other right click options) it wouldn't take in the "ply" command bar and I wanted to know why or how to get it to cooperate.

Comment: OK, so that's brass tacks. The answer is that you don't hide it. These are your  clients, and they may have a good reason to click it.  Disabling parts of the UI in your client's software (yes, Excel belongs to them) to work around bugs that you've introduced is hardly the correct way to approach problems like this.

Comment: Ok, I understand that I shouldn't hide it, but is it possible?

Comment: Sorry (hit enter and posted the earlier comment). I understand you think I shouldn't hide it from a UX perspective, but from a coding perspective is it possible? Just because it may not be ideal for my clients/users (which I don't completely agree with, as the moment they deactivate my workbook, all their functionality is returned) can't I try to learn/understand why the code runs but doesn't change the menu (as it does with other commandbars)? If it's not possible, that's fine and can be the solution but I just wonder if it's possible and how to do it. Thanks for your input, though.